# I'm getting this Pyinstaller error. How do I fix this Pyinstaller error?

Tags: python, module, pycharm, syntax-error, pyinstaller

I was making python file to exe file, and I got error:

pyinstaller:'pyinstaller' The term is not recognized as a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program name. Verify that the name is correct and contain a path
Please verify that the path is correct and then try again.
위치 줄:1 문자:1

- pyinstaller -F -w Text.py
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pyinstaller:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Is PyInstaller installed and where is it installed?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, please check Pyinstaller is installed. If you install `pip install PyInstaller`, it should work `pyinstaller script.py` command.

Secondly, could you try `python -m PyInstaller script.py` ?